# Is Wikipedia correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, distribution-tails

[Cantelli's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality)

Wikipedia says:

$$P[X-\mu \geq a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ for $a > 0$

and

$$P[X-\mu\geq a] \geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ for $a <0$.

Is the second inequality (for $a<0$) correct?

If yes, do you know a proof? Or do you know a paper where it is referenced, as I don't trust this Wikipedia site (it's just a stub).

I'm not sure whether it is the same or whether there's a contradiction, but [here](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2011/Spring-694/lectures/l4.pdf) is another paper where These inequalities are listed.

This paper says for $a>0$:

$$P[X \geq \mu + a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$

$$P[X \leq \mu - a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$

When I take the second formula of the paper and try to transform it into the Wikipedia equation, I get a Problem for discrete functions, as:

$$Pr[X-\mu \geq a]=Pr[X \geq \mu + a]=1-Pr[X \leq \mu + a -1] =1-Pr[X \leq \mu -(-a + 1)] \geq 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+(-a+1)^2}$$

Is my Derivation or one of These equations wrong?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: So is $$P[X-\mu \geq a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ true for discrete random variables?

Is $$P[X-\mu \geq a] \geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ true for discrete random variables?

Is $$P[X\geq \mu +a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ true for discrete random variables and is
$$P[X \leq \mu - a] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ true for discrete random variables?

Answer (score 1):

The second inequality can be deduced from the first by replacing $X$ with $-X$.

---

Note that

$$P[X-\mu\geq a] \geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$

for $a <0$ implies that

$$P[X\geq \mu + a] \geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$

implies that  (since the distribution is continuous, with no discrete part)

$$P[X\leq \mu + a] \leq  \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$

implies that for $b = - a$ (and so now $ b > 0 $),

$$P[X\leq \mu - b] \leq  \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+b^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I almost wanted to accept it and thus Close this question when I saw a Problem:

Could you tell me which of the two sites is correct, when we have a discrete Distribution function? because I think These two Versions are only equivalent under assumption of a continuous random variable $X$?

Or do I oversee something?

Comment: @user146358 Yes, they are equivalent under the assumption of a (purely) continuous random variable, as explained in my edit. In particular, we need $P[X = \mu + a] = 0 $ (otherwise, use strict inequality signs).

Comment: Ok, this means that Wikipedia is correct, also for discrete random variables (without being forced to use strict inequality signs), and the inequalities in the paper are only correct for continuous variables or using strict inequality signs?

Comment: which one is the correct one for discrete random variables?